# How to implement a delay in ActionListener in Swings?

Tags: java, swing

I have a Swing application where I wish to add some delay. I have a close button, which on clicking should display the JTextArea which displays "Closing database connections...." and then execute Database.databaseClose() method and System.exit(). I have tried using Thread.sleep() method as in the code below for the delay. When I execute the program, the screen freezes for 2 seconds and then closes without displaying the JTextArea. The close button and JTextArea is added to JFrame directly.

What I want is that on clicking the close button, the JTextArea should be displayed immediately and then the application should delay for 2 seconds before finally implementing the Database.databaseClose() method and exiting the program. The Database.databaseClose() method works just fine.

I am a beginner at Swings and would greatly appreciate it if anyone could modify the code to implement the requirement above. Thanks!

Here's the code snippet:

```
    JButton btnClose = new JButton("Close");
    btnClose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            JTextArea txtrClosingDatabaseConnections = new JTextArea();

            txtrClosingDatabaseConnections.setText("\r\n\tClosing database connections....");

            getContentPane().add(txtrClosingDatabaseConnections);
            validate();
            repaint();

            /*
             try 
             {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
             }
             catch (InterruptedException e2)
             {
                e2.printStackTrace();
             }
            */

            try 
            {
                Database.databaseClose();
            }
            catch (Exception e1) 
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.exit(0);

        }
    });

    getContentPane().add(btnClose);
```

Comment: I tried to use Thread method sleep(). But it freezes the GUI screen for the specified time and exits. The JTextArea is never displayed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hej, this is an example method that initializes an JMenuBar on a JFrame in Swing.

```
private JMenuBar initMenuBar() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");

        exitApp = new JMenuItem("Exit App");
        exitApp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Timer t = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getParent(), "Closing App in 2 Seconds");
                t.start();
            }

        });

        fileMenu.add(exitApp);
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        return menuBar;
    }
```

May it will help you. It creates an `JOptionPane`, which must be closed by clicking OK, then the `JFrame` will be closed after 2 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is executing on the Event Dispatch Thread, so you can't use a Thread.sleep() since that will block the EDT and prevent it from repainting the GUI.

You need to use a separate Thread for you database processing. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information as well as a solution that uses a `SwingWorker` to manager this Thread for you.

Answer (score 3):

> The Timer is the solution. The Swing timer's task is performed in the event dispatch thread. This means that the task can safely manipulate components, but it also means that the task should execute quickly.

You can use Swing timers in two ways:

1. `To perform a task once, after a delay.`
   For example, the tool tip manager uses Swing timers to determine when to show a tool tip and when to hide it.
2. `To perform a task repeatedly.`
   For example, you might perform animation or update a component that displays progress toward a goal.

Please go through http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html for more details.